# Prevent delegate method from being called too often

Tags: ios, objective-c, delay

How would you add a delay between certain method being called?

This is my code that I want to only trigger 30 times per second:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView {
   [self performSelector:@selector(needsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.033];
}

- (void) needsDisplay {
    [captureView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

If I leave it like this, it only gets called after the user stopped scrolling.

What I want to do is call the method when the user is scrolling, but with a delay of 33 milliseconds between each call.

Comment: You could do it also by checking the offset instead of the time, and if the offset is larger than a threshold value, call the delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a solution, and other scroll view delegate methods weren't good, I did it by limiting based on scroll view's content offset, as suggested in a comment. (Ex: only calling it if the user scrolled more then 3 pixels).

This is a decent solution, since I doubt someone can scroll more then 90 pixels per second and STILL read the text in between those 90 pixels.

```
if (ABS(self.oldOffset.y - webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y) > 3) {
    [captureView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Accept this as an answer if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are different delegate methods which will call on different occausion. This method will only call when user finish scrolling. So you can perform some task if you want to. If you want to do some thing while scrolling or before scrolling you can use different delegate method. Select one of the below depending on your functionality.

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

For detail description upon these delegates please follow this link.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html
Delegate should call when it should be... other wise you gonna cause some glitch.

Comment: that's preferable by far I agree.. delaying a delegate only makes sense if there is no appropriate alternative

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method will get called, you can't setup a limit in that. I think a good option for you is to add the operations in `NSOperationQueue`, and since you are calling the same selector again and again, make sure you only keep a maximum of 30 operations in the queue at the same time. [NSOperationQueue Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: sure you can cancel/reschedule -- thats how setNeedsDisplay & co work

Comment: a operation queue isn't the same as delaying it at all

Comment: Yes you can, NSOperationQueue provides the following methods:
`addOperations:waitUntilFinished:`, `cancelAllOperations`, `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`. These methods can be used to manage operations. Plus `operationCount` property or `maxConcurrentOperationCount` or `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:` to set the maximum count.

Comment: @Daij-Djan: See his question. He wants the method calling to be limited to 30 times per second. He doesn't seem to be talking about delaying.

Comment: whatever you know he doesn't want it anyway

Comment: queuing up the scroll events make no sense

Comment: you'd queue 100 events per sec (just an example) and then do them over-time .. for minutes

Comment: No, you can add operation only if `operationCount <= 30`. Also he can set the limit of concurrentOperation using `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.

Answer (score -1):

One cannot have the control over the calling of the delegate methods, and also there is no parameter to set how often delegate method should call or to set the sensitivity of the scrollview,

U cannot control it.

Only thing remaining is to ignoring the call (return at the beginning of the function call if you do not need that) or else process the call..

Comment: low quality and a dupe

Comment: Fine, can u elaborate "low quality and dupe" ?, I just suggested the generic solution to the problem instead of specific solution

Comment: Any answer here says that you cannot control the delegate and the comment 'to ignore the call' isn't helping with this question